# How to limit the amount of inbound requests to my node http server by putting the rest into a queue

Tags: node.js, httpserver

So i currently have a node server running using the built in http module that is doing some heavy CPU computations, so I only want to allow 10 *inbound* requests at I time. I saw people some people using `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 10;` to limit the amount of outbound connections, but this still allows over 10 conncurrent connections to my server

I also saw people using `server.maxConnections = 10;` but this just straight up rejects any connections after 10.

I want a way to limit *inbound* connections using the http module that allows me to only accept 10 open connections at once, and then put the rest into some kind of queue that will be processed once one of the other connections is finished. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this concept is about throttling requests . there is a package in express you can use that . try this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-throttle

and for stand alone http request you can use :

https://github.com/chilts/oibackoff

https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-rate-limiter

but about your case, you need to limit the usage of route per period of time. you can use :
https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue

Comment: But i am not using the express library, is there a way to do this using the native http module?

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt there are tons of packages there you can use. check the answer

Comment: So it seems like most of these libraries handle limiting request you make from the client, i want to be able to limit the amount of requests coming to my server on the server itself.

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt check the last link

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt check this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/55194891/5677187

Comment: A ha! The second response on that stack overflow question solved the issue for me (because coincidentally i am using puppeteer as well, what are the odds). Thanks!