# Queue of requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rest, queue

I have REST NodeJS server with typescript and Express. One of endpoints call via service another service from another server. This server can process just one request per time. And if 2 users calls my endpoint on my server, NodeJS calls 2 times endpoint on another server, and another server returns 500 error for all requests.

Exists some way to create some queue of requests on my server to send they sequentially?

I need to return response from another server to client which calls endpoint on my server

Thanks!

Comment: Could you rephrase your problem? My understanding is that your server fails on parrallel requests. A simple fix to that is remove any async call server side, but this means that requests will all be queued and processed synchronously which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I use p-queue library, and every request will be add to queue which has concurrency parameter 1, and waiting promise from it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55194891/12196114