# Queuing HTTP request in HTTP server and Express js

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes

We have an web application that handle its http requests by Express js.
Sometime the requests suddenly multiplies and our services going to be scale in our k8s cluster but they will be pending, because we don't have enough resources in our cluster (we have a microservice architecture).
Now, I want to know is there any way to queue these requests in Express js or http server side and gradually route them to our services into cluster?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Scaling of applications in kubernetes cluster happens very fast (if everything is optimized). Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192900/nodejs-http-request-queue)? Or what exactly?