# Pause/queue requests in Express until API connection becomes available

Tags: javascript, api, express, server, routes

I need to implement a queue of requests in Express. For example, if the API endpoint is currently processing a request and a several other requests hit the same endpoint before the first has completed I want to pause the requests and process in sequence when the endpoint becomes available again.

So far I think that setting a global boolean and setting it true/false in the route itself is a possible way to do this.

```
let connAvailable = true

app.post("/api/myEndpoint", async (req, res) => {
  let request = require('request')
  console.log('API CONN AVAILABLE -> ', connAvailable)
  
  if(connAvailable) { 
    connAvailable = false 
    console.log('API CONN AVAILABLE -> ', connAvailable)
    // Make API request here
    request(options, function (error, response) {  
     ...
     if(response) {
      // Request complete - open API for the next request 
      connAvailable = true 
      res.send(response.body)
    }
  }
```

My question is two-fold. Firstly, is this a viable way to approach it. And secondly, how might I handle a backlog of requests and process them correctly in sequence as the API becomes available.

Note, that this app will be handling pretty low volume of requests and, although it is possible that multiple requests will hit the same endpoint simultaneously, it could happen.

More importantly, the reason why I need to implement it this way is that the API being used in the request will only allow one unique data request at a time.

If anyone has any suggestions or advice on how to achieve this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Does this answers to your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192900/nodejs-http-request-queue

Comment: @Georgemff thanks for the link. Some other tasks came up so I haven't yet got around to looking deeper into it. I will check your suggestion as soon as I get the chance.